# Given the set $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert z\rvert >5, \Re(z)<0\}$, how to represent $B=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: w= -iz+2, z\in A\} $?

Tags: complex-numbers, transformation, plane-geometry

Of course $A$ is the left semiplane deprived of the semicircle of radius $5$. I haven't been able to make $B$ explicit writing $w$ in trigonometric notation, and I don't think that is the way.
Using the algebraic notation, $B=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: w= y+2-ix, (x,y)\in A\}.$  I thought I should make some transformations to the graph of $A$: firstly I would shift it up by two units ($y\mapsto y+2$), then reflect the result about the y-axis ($x\mapsto -x$) and then swap the new x and y coordinates (which should mean rotate the graph by 90 degrees clockwise and then rotate it by 180 degrees around the new x-axis). Is this correct?

Comment: It seems so.... You probably want a closed form where you would solve for $w$ in terms of the conditions on $z$.

 How did you get those steps, btw?

I would have thought applying the transformations: $z \mapsto -iz$ then applying $z \mapsto z + 2$ in that order.

Comment: @user357980: If there is a closed form, I guess I want it, but the exercise might not requre it. It does say just "represent these sets". As for the trasfomations, the order of them doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Rotate A clockwise by 90 degrees, then shift this by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , though a more effective way of describing the last step is "reflect the graph about the line y=x "